# Edit end of line in Notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

I am trying to add characters at the end of every line. Those characters are a comma and a name (same for all the columns) as well as a number (incrementing from 1 to end number). My columns are not regular and I have many lines so I need to find the expression to use in the Find and Replace.

My document looks like this:

```
1,-16 37 25.3,65 32 36.1
2,-16 18 5.9,66 6 37.9
3,-16 17 54.3,66 6 58.7
4,-15 59 23.3,66 40 9.2
5,-15 59 8.2,66 40 36.3
```

I need it to look like that:

```
1,-16 37 25.3,65 32 36.1,ECS1
2,-16 18 5.9,66 6 37.9,ECS2
3,-16 17 54.3,66 6 58.7,ECS3
4,-15 59 23.3,66 40 9.2,ECS4
5,-15 59 8.2,66 40 36.3,ECS5
```

Does anyone know the appropriate expression?

Answer (score 2):

If you select "Regular expression" in the Replace dialog then you can match the leading character and the remainder using `^(\d)(.*)$` in the "Find what" field and replace it using the captured parts in the "Replace with" field: `\1\2,ECS\1` where backslash-digit gets substituted with the captured match from one of the parenthetical match expressions.

Comment: More about regular expressions: http://letconex.blogspot.com/2013/06/how-to-use-regular-expressions-in.html